# Current input of discmans and walkmans

Tags: dc-ac

For discmans and walkmans who operate on 1.5V, 3V, or 6V, what current output (in amp.) of DC/AC convertor, as alternative to using batteries, should be used? The discmans and walkmans do not specify the current input on their labels nor manuals.  Thanks.

Comment: What type of battery do they use? Look into the current ratings of that size carbon-zinc battery.

Comment: For many years, many Walkmans used rechargeable batteries in custom shaped modules.

Comment: Re.  batteries.  Some models use 1 AA battery (total 1.5V), some use 2 AA batteries (total 3 V), while some use 4 AA batteries (total 6 V).

Comment: No sensible electronics engineer would design a circuit to draw more than one amp from a AA cell, and probably limit it to half an amp. This approach is basically a simpler form of Ali Chen's answer; look at the limitations of the current power supply, and as long as your replacement is better than that, you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You measure the current using a DMM (digital multi meter) on a current measuring scale. When making the measurement it can be best to use brand new batteries because the higher voltage may increase the current drawn by the circuitry. In some cases where newer types of devices may contain a switching power supply for voltage level conversion you may also need to check the current draw on a battery that has been used quite a bit and may exhibit lower voltage.

If the device uses standard type batteries such as AA or AAA in a battery compartment one way to conveniently measure the current is to make up small thin assembly that you can slip into the battery compartment between one end of a battery and the compartment contact or spring. This thin assembly needs to have conductive metal on each side that then attaches to a pair of short wires, one on each side, that can extend out of the battery compartment for attachment to the meter leads.

A simple scheme would be to use some heavy paper card stock and glue a piece of aluminium foil on each side. Make this the width of a battery but about twice as high. Once inserted into the battery compartment you could simply hold the current meter probes to two sides of the assembly so that the battery circuit is completed through the meter.

Comment: If you're giving it a regulated input voltage, rather than a varying battery voltage, I would think you just need to measure the current it takes at that specific voltage range.

Comment: @Felthry - Well the question was to know how much current the unit draws before the OP figures out what power supply to design or acquire. My suggestions are directed toward determining the worst case current draw.

Comment: Felthry, sorry the question might have been confusing.

Comment: I was referring to several pieces of discmans and walksmans, not one piece with variable voltage.

Comment: Michael Karas, thank you for your elaborate answer.  However, I have not got a DMM.  Is there an easy way for 'non-electrical' consumers like me to find out which AC-DC conv. is suitable:  they each come with variable voltage output selector but each of them has a fixed maximum current ouput (800mA or 1500mA).  Which one is to be used?  I read that a current output from the convertor that is higher than the current input to the device is no problem, but not the if the output is lower.  The issue now is none of the devices state what current input it requires (although voltage input is stated).

Comment: @FEP - You can buy DMMs of as little as $8 to $20 on Amazon. If you are going to do things like this you should get one. You could choose to get the larger current capacity AC to DC adapter and just see if it works but trial and error could end up costing you what it would take to purchase a low cost DMM and then be smart about your adapter purchase.

Comment: Do you know why the devices do not state their current input?  The manufacturers have created a hole to enable connection to electric mains supply as an alternative to using batteries (AA or AAA), and stated their voltage input and polarity, yet have not mentioned their current input knowing that a wrong input could cause damage.  Have I overlooked something or been using the wrong terms here?

Comment: @FEP - I have no idea. When I need to know an answer to something that is not specified I simply just measure it. I try to not get stymied by unanswerable questions for something that is simple to check. Some manufacturers will have provided a compatible AC/DC adapter with their unit when it was purchased and in that case the ratings would have most likely been written on the adapter.

Comment: @FEP While it's possible for a too-low current (or too-low voltage out of a current-limited supply) to cause damage, it's not as common as damage from a too-high voltage, and a power supply that is capable of supplying more current than is needed wouldn't damage it (since these power supplies are voltage-regulated, not current-regulated, and they won't force more current through than it needs). So most likely the worst thing that could happen if you use the wrong power supply, as long as it's the right voltage, is that the device simply doesn't work. So the current rating is less important.

Comment: @FEP That's just my guess, though. Their reasoning might have been entirely different, and for all I know, this could be one such device that can be damaged by undervoltage.

Answer (score 0):

Usual walkman/diskmans were specified for a playback time of 6 hours and more. An AA-battery has capacity about 2500 mAh, so it would be safe to assume that in worst case these devices consume no more than ~400-500 mA. So a modern 1-A AC-DC adapter should be just fine in all cases.